# Request reply pattern between 2 app c#

Tags: c#, wcf, request, reply

App1 send a request and wait for app2 to give a reply (true/false) or request time out.

How to do this using c# and wcf.

I managed to send the request but i dont know how to wait and make app2 give a reply

Comment: i'm sorry,
 my code is in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396622/publish-a-message-and-wait-until-replied-or-time-out)

Answer (score 0):

You can use tpl. The library has wait, continue ... methods. You can find docs easily by searching on google.

Comment: what is tpl stands for?

Comment: Task Parallel Library

Answer (score 0):

1. Create WCF application project in Visual Stuio.
2. Project must contains file *.svc, put your method to this file, add contract attributes.
3. Run WCF application, by default browser open new tab with your application url
4. Choose in browser file *.svc and copy (f.e http://localhost:32490/nameOfProject.svc)
5. In second application click on **projcect** in solution explorer(not solution), choose add service reference
6. put link from step 4, and visual studio generate environment with client classes.
7. to call method on client create instance of {NameOfYourApplication}ServiceClient class from step 6.